# socket.on method not calling during getting message from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I am working on socket programming and I am new to socket. I got stuck. I am able to send the message on server easily but not able to get the message from the server. This could mean that my socket.on() method not working.
My socket connection code is

```
-(void)socketSession
{
    NSString *strURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:URl];
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURl];

        socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url options:@{@"log": @YES, @"forcePolling": @YES}];
    [socket connect];
    [self recieveServerMessage];


    [socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
        NSLog(@"socket connected");


      }];

}
```

I call this method on `viewDidLoad` in viewController class and `recieveServermessage` method is

```
-(void)recieveServerMessage{

    NSLog(@"receiving...message...");


    [socket on:@"chat" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
        NSLog(@"recieveMessage");

    }];

}
```

My control don't come when message is sent by server.
and below format is given by web server client

```
socket.on(":chat", function(data) {
// fired when any chat message is raised
// data.to_id = my _id. Please verify this before processing the packet
// data.sender_id = sender's _id. Map against counsellor list API or /api/getUserName?_id=(user's _id)
// data.msg = text message sent by the sender
})
```

Now please guide me. I have been stuck on this the last two days.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Full code of socket io javascript class will be helpful.

You need to write `emit` function to send message from server to client. Like:

```
sockets.emit('chat', message);
```

And from client to server:

```
[socket emit:@"chat" withItems:@[@"message", @"other data"]];
```

Comment: socket.emit used for send message to server but this part working. I am not able to get message from server means socket.on method not called

Comment: from server did you call emit to send message to client?

Comment: Actually I have a online websites having chat functionality which used socket in backend.But same functionality working in android.Android developer getting message from server using socket.on method.

Comment: If android app gets message iOS app should also get message. Without total code I am not understanding what actual problem is. Did you see "socket connected" log? You can try [self recieveServerMessage]; after socket connected.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.Main problem was in socket handshake. Now I am using

```
 NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://unbottle.me"];

socket =  [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url
                                            options:@{@"connectParams" : @{@"_id": userID,@"isCounsellor": @NO,@"counsellor_id": counsellorID}}];
```

Earlier I was not using @"connectParams" key value in dictionary so I was facing this issue.
Thanks